# How to add a row to np array in for loop python

Tags: python, arrays, for-loop, append, np

After I read some answers to similar questions here this is my code:

```py
check = np.empty((1,2), int)
for i in range(1,20):

   clf = KNeighborsClassifier(n_neighbors= i) 
   clf.fit(X_train, y_train)
   print("Test set accuracy for k = ", i , "is: " , clf.score(X_test, y_test)) 
   check = np.append(check, np.array ([[i ,clf.score(X_test, y_test)]]) )
```

I want to  get a 19×2 (2D array) with the values.

The problems are :

1. I'm getting a 1D array
2. The first two elements are added when I create the array, and I don't want them included.

Comment: Your np.array() call in the last line has two brackets. Try removing one set.

Answer (score 0):

If the `axis` parameter of [append](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.append.html?highlight=append#numpy.append) is None, the values will be flattened and added to your array. 
Try with:

```
   check = np.append(check, [[i ,clf.score(X_test, y_test)]], axis=0)
```

Answer (score 0):

First off, if you don't need to dynamically scale your array, I'd recommend not appending with numpy. Instead since you know what size array that you want, I'd instead recommend initializing a numpy array of that size, and then setting the value by index as iterate through the loop.

```
check = np.empty((19, 2), int)
for i in range(1, 20):
   clf = KNeighborsClassifier(n_neighbors=i) 
   clf.fit(X_train, y_train)
   print("Test set accuracy for k = ", i , "is: " , clf.score(X_test, y_test)) 
   check[i, 0] = i
   check[i, 1] = clf.score(X_test, y_test)
```

If you're using this check array to just see the results of different number of neighbors, I might recommend using a dict instead. A dict will make navigating your results easier, and has the same structure that you're getting now with an Nx2 dimension array. The code would look like this if you used a dict.

```
check = {}
for i in range(1, 20):
   clf = KNeighborsClassifier(n_neighbors=i) 
   clf.fit(X_train, y_train)
   print("Test set accuracy for k = ", i , "is: " , clf.score(X_test, y_test)) 
   check[i] = clf.score(X_test, y_test)
```

So now, you have the number of neighbors represented as the keys of your dict, and the values are the score of that model. So the value of `check[14]` would be the the score for the model with 14 neighbors. This also gives you the advantage of being able to call `check.keys()` to be able to see which values that you've already tried. So if instead you wanted to try only 1, 3, 5, and 10 neighbors, it's as simple as changing the code to

```
check = {}
for i in [1, 3, 5, 10]:
   clf = KNeighborsClassifier(n_neighbors=i) 
   clf.fit(X_train, y_train)
   print("Test set accuracy for k = ", i , "is: " , clf.score(X_test, y_test)) 
   check[i] = clf.score(X_test, y_test)
```